# Парсинг невалидного кода страницы

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, с парсингом данного сайта: http://wekings.ru/
Возможно, даже на него нужно зайти...

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.taishet.ru/horoscope/';

$start = 'БЛИЗНЕЦЫ (22 мая - 21 июня)';

$finish = 'РАК (22 июня - 23 июля)';

function parser($url,$start,$finish) {

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $position1 = strpos($content, $start);
    $position2 = strpos($content, $finish);
    $content = substr($content, $position1, $position2-$position1);
    $content = strip_tags($content, '<p><a>');
    //echo nl2br($content);
    echo ($content);
    return $content;
}

parser($url, $start, $finish);
```

Пытался данным кодом, что на обычных сайтах парсит, а в http://wekings.ru/ пустая страница

Answer (score 1):

Еще один СЕОшник? По коду парсить хотите tasishet.ru, а зайти предлагаете на weekings.ru.  Вы не можете понять, что написали?

**Обновление**

Насколько я понимаю, надо быть зарегистрированным на сайте с игрой, чтобы получать с него информацию. Сервер, на котором вы запускаете скрипт, там не зарегистрирован и, следовательно, не имеет доступа к данным того сайта. Для работы надо разбираться в методах аутентификации, используемых на том сайте, и эмулировать их на сервере.

Comment: Напишите, что именно вы хотите получить и из чего. На сайте предлагается поиграть в каких-то Викингов, не надо заниматься глупым СЕО.

Comment: Я взялся за этот сайт, потому что с него не могу вытянуть информацию, данный код, что привел в пример, работает и вытаскивает информацию с того сайта о погоде.

Comment: Любую информацию с него вытащить, дальше я сам разберусь.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: В этом я совсем дуб, пример указать есть возможность?

Comment: @romaaa32 - лень писать, но почитайте тут

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php